# Finding the fourth roots of $-16$?

Tags: complex-analysis

A question in my textbook is: *Find the roots of $(-16)^{1/4}$*.

So, what I did was use the equation provided by the textbook and got:

$(-16)^{1/4}= 16^{1/4} \cdot (-1)^{1/4}=2 \cdot (-1)^{1/4}= 2\cdot exp{\frac{i(\pi + 2\pi k)}{4}}$.

Hence, the solutions are all the aforementioned values such that $k \in {0,1,2,3}$.

But my question now is: *Why isn't $2\cdot exp(i* \pi)$ a solution*? $-1$ in polar coordinates occurs at $\theta = \pi$, so why is that not a solution?

Thanks for looking!

-Bliebervik

Comment: $2\cdot\exp(i\pi)=-2$, and $(-2)^4\neq-16$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28-16%29%5E%281%2F4%29
The simple reason that can't be a solution is because $(2e^{i\pi})^4 = 16$, and not -16.

Comment: No problem sir!

Answer (score 3):

$\exp(i\pi)=-1$

$(2\exp(i\pi))^4=(-2)^4\ne-16$